# Post value to controller by input field in the Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

This code make button to delete action in Laravel.
When this button clicked, then modal box show.
but when I clicked Stop button, then I couldn't insert any data into modal input box because this code just passed away instead of chance to insert input text :(

How can I modify this code?

**Stop button by Collective in the Laravel**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['jobs.destroy', $job->id], 'method' => 'delete', 'class' => 'btn-group', 'id' => 'jobStop']) !!}
{!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs', 'id' => 'jobStop']) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('stop_comment', $job->stop_comment, ['id' => 'jobComment']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Modal box**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="jobStopModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Er du sikker på å stoppe jobb?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Kommentar:</p>
          <input type="text" id="jobStopComment">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Lukk</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Lagre endringer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#jobStop').on('click', function (e) {
     $("#jobStopModal").modal("show");
});
$('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
    var newStopComment = $('input#jobStopComment').val();
    $('#jobComment').val(newStopComment);
    $('#jobStopModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: `because this code just passed away` - what does this mean, exactly? Do you mean that the page reloads, and the modal disappears?

Comment: @Don'T Panic, modal once showing and disappear with in a second.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I posted an answer, does it help?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, yes it work find, thanks :) 
by the way, if I use button type as `button` instead of `submit`, then could this be an easier way without using `preventDefault()` ?

Comment: [Only if you also set `type` to _button_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).  Using `preventDefault()` is standard and very common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript is opening the modal, but in the background the form was really submitted, so will load whatever the form's `action` was.

You need to prevent the form submission within your Javascript like so:

```
$('#jobStop').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    // <-- prevent normal form submission
    $("#jobStopModal").modal("show");
});
```

Also, you have 2 elements with ID `jobStop`.  IDs should be unique, and this is especially important as you are using them to target elements in your Javascript.

```
{!! Form::open([ ...    'id' => 'jobStop']) !!}
{!! Form::button(' ...  'id' => 'jobStopButton']) !!}
```

If you change the button ID you of course need to update your JS event handler:

```
$('#jobStopButton').on('click', function (e) {
```